run uiautomatorviewer
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
I have a little problem when running uiautomatorviewer on Android as above. Can anyone tell me how to fix the error? Thank you.
I have set environment variables, installed java jdk,...
